# Nginx crashes on tls_process_client_hello:version too low

Tags: nginx

I'm no devops and I have this problem which crashes whole server and requires me to manually restart it.

```
Mar 11 17:20:26 ip-serv-ip-he-re nginx[725]: 2019/03/11 17:20:26 [crit]
758#758: *5398 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D18C:SSL 
routines:tls_process_client_hello:version too low) while SSL handshaking,
client: my.ip.he.re, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

What can be causing that? It's really not good to not know when it will crash again.

Comment: did you find any solution to this?